# Linked data in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, rdbms, database

I am developing a POS system to a spare parts store which maintains lot of items in its database. There is an item table in my database. In this Business scenario there may be alternative parts to a particular part. If we consider A and B parts I want to link B as an alternative of A. I have a table called tbl_alternative and records data like below. 
    A’s id = 1, B’s Id =2
    Primary key is alternative_id
              [image]

It keeps B as an alternative of A and A as an alternative of B. The system users wants to link any part as an alternative of another and view the relation. If there is more parts linked as alternative of B, all of them should linked to A when B links to A. My Question is how I handle this kind of scenario in MySQL. Actually I’m so confused now. Admire if anyone can give a good solution to save my life. 

Comment: I don't even see any question mark.

Answer (score 0):

I would organize the parts into "groups" with three tables like so.

```
Parts:
----------------
|id|description|
|1 |  .......  |
|2 |  .......  |
|3 |  .......  |
|4 |  .......  |
----------------

Groups:
----------------
|id|description|
|1 |    ....   |
|2 |   ....    |
----------------

PartGroup:
------------------
|part_id|group_id|
|1      |1       |
|2      |1       |
|3      |1       |
|1      |2       |
|4      |2       |
------------------
```

This sort of set up would handle having more than two parts be swappable and it would handle one part being a member of multiple groups.

For instance in my example, parts 1, 2, and 3 are swappable and parts 1 and 4 are swappable but 2 and 4 aren't.

Comment: ok guys..thanks a lot..i think the best solution is a keep a category table for all parts and group parts for relevant category.thanks again Rudi Angela and Drew Galbraith.:)

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the different parts are alternatives to each other means they can all fulfill a certain function/use/role, e.g. 'temperature sensor'. You should make a table listing these functions and then link the parts table to this table. Most probably this will be a one to may link where a function can be fulfilled by several parts, in which case the parts table will have a foreign key to the function table. If a part can fulfill several functions then the relationship should be many to many, in which case you will need a coupling table. this table has only two columns: function_id and part_id.